# Laptop RAM upgradation Issue

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I have Samsung lapatop with 2 Gb RAM and i want to upgrade it . Now the question is my laptop has 2 slots. 1 filled wih 2gb ram and another one is empty. that empty slot i want to fillup with another 4 gb ram(which makes 6gb total). 2 Gb Ram specification is DDR3-1333MHz-204pin SODIMMM RAM(PC3-10600S) and manufacture code is M471B5773CHS-CH9....Now i am going to buy another 4gb RAM which has manufactring code is M471B5273CHS-CH9 (rest specs are same). so should i buy this RAM? i mean will there be some compatibility issue? or which kind of RAM should I prefer?(tell me specs if you can)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This should be fine depending on your model (which you never stated), but I would check a few things like the maximum memory your laptops supports using the owners manual, manufacturer's support site, or a memory retailer like Crucial (they have a tool to show what memory is compatible and the maximum allowed). Also remember that to take advantage of 4+ GB of RAM, you must have a 64-bit operating system installed or anything beyond ~3.75GB will not be usable.

Comment: hi @acejavelin... i hv 64bit Win7 home basic OS  and i can extend upto 8 GB ram max.(i hv already checked that).  anyway thanks for giving ur valuable time for putting ur comments to my question

Answer (score 0):

The most important characteristics when changing RAM are:

- RAM size (SODIMM in your case)
- RAM type (DDR3)
- RAM version (PC3-10600)

From what I found on Google, that 4GB ram you found has the same parameters, so there should be no compatibility problem.

However, as far as I know you can only get the best perfomance when using a pair of two identical ram modules. So I would recommend you buy a second 2GB M471B5773CHS-CH9, or in the best scenario, two 4GB M471B5273CHS-CH9.

**EDIT**: Using two identical module for best performance is not true, thanks acejavelin for pointing it out. Still, I'd recommend two 4GB ram (because one never has enough ram ^^)

Comment: @NathanShiraini The matched pair scenario only applies when the device supports "dual channel" memory mode, most consumer and average business/enterprise laptops do not require dual channel memory if they support it at all. In typical day to day use, dual channel memory will not increase performance noticeably.